# Problema de consulta LAST value en consulta first, last,max,min

Tags: mysql

Mi problema es que en la consulta funciona tal cual regresando el ultimo valor del grupo

```
 SELECT p.promediototalmk
        FROM promediogeneral
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM promediogeneral
            GROUP BY fecha
        ) ORDER BY id DESC
```

pero cuando hago la consulta completa me regresa es el primer valor y no el ultimo

```
    SELECT hora,
(SELECT p.promediototalmk FROM promediogeneral GROUP BY fecha ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS OPEN,
(SELECT p.promediototalmk
FROM promediogeneral
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM promediogeneral
    GROUP BY fecha
) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS CLOSE,
  
    
    MIN(promediototalmk) AS ProMin, MAX(promediototalmk) AS ProMax, p.`fecha` as FECHA 
FROM promediogeneral p
GROUP BY `fecha` ORDER BY id DESC
```

La respuesta es Close que esta regresando mal

**RESULT**

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2020-06-15,>>205881.018<<,206615.32,200749.62,>>205881.018<<,0,0
2020-06-14,203554.647,205730.58,199753.08,203554.647,0,0
2020-06-13,201731.652,205091.68,199225.86,201731.652,0,0
```